# how ti unnest a postgres table with unique row numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can i have unique and progressive row numbers as result of unnesting a table with arrays inside column?
Now I'm getting same id numbers for each originating row that has been unnested...
Thanks in advance

@edited post:

Here is the starting table

[image: Starting table]

that after this query:

```
SELECT 
t1.id,
t1.data,
t1.int,
unnest(string_to_array(translate(t1.id_int, '{}', ''), ','))::integer AS aid,
t1.note
FROM t1
ORDER BY t1.date DESC;
```

becomes

[image: unnested table]

Desired output would be a column with unique ids, something like that:

[image: desired output]

P.S. I'm using PG v.11 and I'd like to create a new view (not a new table) by means of a right SQL syntax

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) so that it can be copied and pasted. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Note that `unnest(string_to_array(translate(t1.id_int, '{}', ''), ','))` can be simplified to `unnest(t1.id_int)`

Comment: to @a_horse_with_no_name: mine is not a proper array[] postgres field, that column is in text format so unnest(t1.id_int) doesn't work in my case, I have to use string_to_array() function before....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of each element in the array, you can use `with ordinality` together with `unnest()`.

To create a unique ID over all rows, not just the array elements, use a window function.

```
select row_number() over (order by t1.id, u.idx), 
       t1.date, 
       t1.int,
       u.aid, 
       t1.note
from t1
  cross join unnest(id_int) with ordinality as u(aid, idx)
order by 1
```